# Define a parameter as an array of specifics types in typescript3

Tags: reactjs, typescript

here is my code :

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const Suggestions = (props:any) => {
  const options = props.results.map((r: { id: number ; name: string; }) => (
    <li key={r.id}>
      {r.name}
    </li>
  ))
  return <ul>{options}</ul>
}

export default Suggestions
```

but i would like to define r as an array of { id: number ; name: string; }

not just { id: number ; name: string; }

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[]` at the end of the inline interface definition to make it as an array type.

```
const options = props.results.map((r: { id: number ; name: string; }[]) => (
```

---

Or you can use `Array<T>` with the inline interface defenition.

```
const options = props.results.map((r: Array<{ id: number ; name: string; }>) => (
```

Comment: Also `Array<{ id: number ; name: string; }>` looks better for complex types

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir : yes